# How to include template files in WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to include page templates files on my WordPress plugin to display the 'job' custom post type on the front end.

The problem :
The templates load properly on the single page of the custom post type, but the other pages are blank (showing nothing but white blank page), including the homepage, wp default post and wp default page.

Can you please tell me my mistake and how to solve this?
Thank you.

Here's the code :

```
function dwwp_load_templates( $original_template ) {

    if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) !== 'job' ) {
        return;
    }


    if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) {
        if( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory().'/archive-job.php' ) ){
            return get_stylesheet_directory().'/archive-job.php';
        }else{
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'templates/archive-job.php';
        }
    } elseif( is_singular('job') ) {
        if( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory().'/single-job.php' ) ){
            return get_stylesheet_directory().'/single-job.php';
        }else{
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'templates/single-job.php';
        }

    } else {
        return get_page_template();
    }
    return $original_template;

}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'dwwp_load_templates' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just say `return`. You must return some template. Fix this lines

````
if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) !== 'job' ) {
return $original_template;
} 
```
````

Answer (score 1):

In order for the templates to work we need to be able to locate the right templates when they are called. With the following code the plugin first look for the called template file in `themes/your-theme/woocommerce-plugin-templates/{template-name}`, if that isn’t found it will search in your main theme file `themes/your-theme/{template-name}` and falls back to the original plugin templates in `plugins/woocommerce-plugin-templates/templates/{template-name}`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Locate template.
 *
 * Locate the called template.
 * Search Order:
 * 1. /themes/theme/woocommerce-plugin-templates/$template_name
 * 2. /themes/theme/$template_name
 * 3. /plugins/woocommerce-plugin-templates/templates/$template_name.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param   string  $template_name          Template to load.
 * @param   string  $string $template_path  Path to templates.
 * @param   string  $default_path           Default path to template files.
 * @return  string                          Path to the template file.
 */
function wcpt_locate_template( $template_name, $template_path = '', $default_path = '' ) {

    // Set variable to search in woocommerce-plugin-templates folder of theme.
    if ( ! $template_path ) :
        $template_path = 'woocommerce-plugin-templates/';
    endif;

    // Set default plugin templates path.
    if ( ! $default_path ) :
        $default_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/'; // Path to the template folder
    endif;

    // Search template file in theme folder.
    $template = locate_template( array(
        $template_path . $template_name,
        $template_name
    ) );

    // Get plugins template file.
    if ( ! $template ) :
        $template = $default_path . $template_name;
    endif;

    return apply_filters( 'wcpt_locate_template', $template, $template_name, $template_path, $default_path );

}
```

The code above locates and return the path to an existing and valid path that can be loaded and included on the page. In order to actually get the template file there is a extra function. The following code can be used directly in the shortcode function to load the files.

```
<?php
/**
 * Get template.
 *
 * Search for the template and include the file.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @see wcpt_locate_template()
 *
 * @param string    $template_name          Template to load.
 * @param array     $args                   Args passed for the template file.
 * @param string    $string $template_path  Path to templates.
 * @param string    $default_path           Default path to template files.
 */
function wcpt_get_template( $template_name, $args = array(), $tempate_path = '', $default_path = '' ) {

    if ( is_array( $args ) && isset( $args ) ) :
        extract( $args );
    endif;

    $template_file = wcpt_locate_template( $template_name, $tempate_path, $default_path );

    if ( ! file_exists( $template_file ) ) :
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf( '<code>%s</code> does not exist.', $template_file ), '1.0.0' );
        return;
    endif;

    include $template_file;

}
```

This code will use the `wcpt_locate_template()` function to find and return the path to a valid template file, when no valid template file is found and the template file doesn’t exist in the plugins’ template folder, which should never occur, a error will be displayed.